# How to add custom text selection in whole body

Tags: html, css

I want to add a custom text background color with a custom text color. In general website, the default text background color is light blue and text color is white but I want to add my site with custom color

```css
::selection {
  background: aquamarine;
  color: black;
}
.custom-text-selection::selection {
  background: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="custom-text-selection">Select some of this text.</p>
```

The above code shows only a single tag custom color. But it irksome's to add the whole website. Is there any way to add all the text with custom colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your solution could be rewrite the ::selection styles to all the DOM components

```
*::selection{
  background: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
```

Or you can apply those styles to all members of an element with an specific classname

```
.custom-section *::selection{
  background: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but if it is to add that style to the entire website, you should just be able to add that css class to the body or hmtl tags:

```
<body class="custom-text-selection">
<!-- Website body goes here -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the below in your css will change the selected text colour and background colour of the whole site:

```css
::selection {
    background-color: deeppink;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.


</p>
```

Comment: @MHHabib Your welcome, please remember to up vote or mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code have two `::selected` rules:

- for all the text -> `background: aquamarine;` & `color: black;`.
- for text with `custom-text-selection` -> `background: deeppink;` & `color: white;`.

You can apply the first rule by creating elements without giving them the `custom-text-selection` tag:

```css
::selection {
  background: aquamarine;
  color: black;
}
.custom-text-selection::selection {
  background: deeppink;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="custom-text-selection">
  Text with custom-text-selection color (deeppink).
</p>

<p>
  Text with ::selection color (aquamarine).
</p>
```